# Where can I get command line arguments?

Tags: c, qt, command-line-arguments

I'm studying C programming in Qt environment.

My program is supposed to take two command-line arguments that are file names, read the characters from the first file one at a time and write the characters in reverse order to the second file. However, the program doesn't execute properly.

The program output is:

```
Usage: copy infile outfile
```

After pressing Enter the program terminates execution.
I suppose there are no command-line arguments.

> Could you please tell me where and how can I get them?

```
//Command-Line Arguments
#include <stdio.h>

void reverseFile( FILE *inPtr, FILE *outPtr );

//function main begins program execution
int main ( int argc, char *argv[])
{
   FILE *inFilePtr;
   FILE *outFilePtr;

   if ( argc != 3 )
   {
       printf("Usage: copy infile outfile\n");
   }
   else
   {
       if ( ( inFilePtr = fopen( argv[1], "r" ) ) != NULL )
       {
           if ( ( outFilePtr = fopen( argv[2], "w" ) ) != NULL )
           {
               reverseFile( inFilePtr, outFilePtr );
           }
           else
           {
               printf("File \"%s\" could not be opened\n", argv[2]);
           }
       } //end if
       else
       {
           printf("File \"%s\" could not be opened\n", argv[1]);
       }
   } //end else
    return 0;
} //end function main

void reverseFile( FILE *inPtr, FILE *outPtr )
{
    int c;

    if ( ( c = fgetc( inPtr ) ) != EOF )
    {
        reverseFile( inPtr, outPtr );
    }
    fputc( c, outPtr );
}
```

Comment: command-line arguments are command-line arguments. Pass them in the command to execute.

Comment: How are you executing the program?

Comment: By the way, you should close your successfully opened files.

Comment: ./outputfile file1 file2 you should run this

Comment: Code is "getting" command line arguments just fine.  The question is how does OP expect to "put" them in the Qt environment.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Qt creator, go on "Projects" on the left panel, select the tab of your project, then "Compile and Execute". In the "Execute" section you have an editbox nammed "Arguments". You can put the path to your files here, for example : ./MyDirectory/file1.txt ./MyDirectory/file2.txt.

Comment: Thanks, William B., for your answer to my question. But, I'm afraid that won't work, as long as this editbox is supposed to take parameters, not arguments. The parameter differs from the argument by representing additional information for a function to perform its task; the argument is the value supplied in the function call.

Comment: Yes i agree with your definitions of arguments and parameters. But the field i am talking to is well supposed to take arguments and not parameters. Maybe i missunderstood your problem or you don't talk about the same field. You can see a screen taken from my interface (sorry it's in French) : [Image of Qt interface here](http://hpics.li/b08a6a7). I tested it with a simple `printf("Arg1 = %s and Arg2 = %s\n", argv[1], argv[2]);` and it works.

Comment: Thank You ever so for such a thorough explanation! In that case, I'll try your option.

Answer (score 0):

At the command line, when you run the program you need to type :

```
copy inFile outFile
```

or replace `copy` with the executable name `inFile` with the name of the input file and `outFile` with the name of the output file. Then inFile and outFile names will be copied to `args[1]` and `args[2]` in your source code.

If you are using Windows you will probably have to type something like

```
copy.exe inFile outFile
```

and if you are using Linux something like

```
./copy inFile outFile
```

If you are using an IDE like Visual Studio or Eclipse you need to configure the arguments passed to your executable when running. Go through the IDE's documentation for that.

Also you mention Qt in your question. Although there is nothing related to Qt in your code, Qt is a C++ framework